# Angular directive with ng-repeat in template not working

Tags: angularjs

This has been asked a few times but it still doesn't seem to work. I have a very basic example. I am not making the mistake running the index.html file in my browser, I am running it on a server.

index.html

```
<div ng-view> </div>


  <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <my-names listcustomers='customer'></my-names>
  </div>
```

template:

```
 <div ng-repeat="listcustomers">

        <table class="box-table" width="100%">

            <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Name: {{listcustomers.name}}</th>
               <th>Age: {{listcustomers.age}}</th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('myApp').
controller("Controller",["$scope", function($scope){

    $scope.customer = [

         {
            name: 'Drew',
            age: 30
         },

         {
            name: 'Meike',
            age: 54
         },

        {
            name: 'Peter',
            age: 25
        }
    ];

}])
    .directive("myNames",function($scope){
        return{
            restrict : 'E',
            transclude : false,
            templateUrl: 'pages/myNames.html',
            scope: {
                listcustomers: "="
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: ng-repeat="customer in listcustomers" and then refer to customer.name

Comment: @KobiCohen when I do that I get an error saying angular.js:12722 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- myNamesDirective

Comment: @KobiCohen got it to work, had to remove the $scope from the directive function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the variable that will be used in the ng-repeat body.  So listcustomers is an array of objects and you need iterate over each element in the array.  Try the following in your template:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in listcustomers">
    <table class="box-table" width="100%">
        <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Name: {{customer.name}}</th>
           <th>Age: {{customer.age}}</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use **in** keyword to iterate using [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) as:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in listcustomers">
  <table class="box-table" width="100%">
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name: {{customer.name}}</th>
       <th>Age: {{customer.age}}</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```